# Why can't I check if my checkboxes have been checked?

Tags: javascript, dom, checkbox

```js
// Register for Activities section of the form.
document.querySelector(".activities").addEventListener("change", function(){
    var main = document.querySelector("all").checked;
    var framework = document.querySelector("js-frameworks").checked;
    var libs = document.querySelector("js-libs").checked;
    var express = document.querySelector("express").checked;
    var node = document.querySelector("node").checked;
    var build = document.querySelector("build-tools").checked;
    var npm = document.querySelector("npm").checked;

    // If the user selects a workshop, don't allow selection of a workshop at the same date and time -- you should disable the checkbox and visually indicate that the workshop in the competing time slot isn't available.
    if(framework == true) {
        express.disabled = true;
    } else if(express == true) {
        framework.disabled = true;
    } else if(libs == true) {
        node.disabled = true;
    } else if(node == true) {
        libs.disabled = true;
    } 

    // When a user unchecks an activity, make sure that competing activities (if there are any) are no longer disabled.
    if(!framework.checked) {
        express.disabled = false;
    } else if(!express.checked) {
        framework.disabled = false;
    } else if(!libs.checked) {
        node.disabled = false;
    } else if(!node.checked) {
        libs.disabled = false;
    } 
});
```

```html
<fieldset class="activities">
            <legend>Register for Activities</legend>
            <label><input type="checkbox" name="all"> Main Conference — $200</label>
            <label><input type="checkbox" name="js-frameworks"> JavaScript Frameworks Workshop — Tuesday 9am-12pm, $100</label>
            <label><input type="checkbox" name="js-libs"> JavaScript Libraries Workshop — Tuesday 1pm-4pm, $100</label>
            <label><input type="checkbox" name="express"> Express Workshop — Tuesday 9am-12pm, $100</label>
            <label><input type="checkbox" name="node"> Node.js Workshop — Tuesday 1pm-4pm, $100</label>          
            <label><input type="checkbox" name="build-tools"> Build tools Workshop — Wednesday 9am-12pm, $100</label>
            <label><input type="checkbox" name="npm"> npm Workshop — Wednesday 1pm-4pm, $100</label>
          </fieldset>
```

I am adding interactivity to a form.

A user will select, via checkboxes, activities that they would like to do.

If a user selects an activity that has a time clash with another. Then that other checkbox will be disable.

I don't want to use jQuery for this.

I am having trouble trying to implement this. The error says it cannot read property 'checked' of null?

What am I doing wrong here? I have tried, mixing up whether I'm trying to call upon values, check properties and have tried quite a few attempted solutions but to no avail.

Comment: do you know what `querySelector` does?

Comment: I thought I did: Returns the first element within the document  that matches the specified group of selectors?

Comment: Well, you don't. :) Selectors for your checkboxes are all wrong. `document.querySelector("[name=all]")` is more like it.

Comment: `querySelector` takes a CSS/jQuery style selector, so you would need `'[name="all"]'`, etc.

Comment: I've used it with other uses in the program and haven't had to do that. I'm confused

Comment: CSS selectors. Read up on them.

Comment: Oh I see. I didn't have trouble before because I was using either ID's or Classes...which ARE CSS selectors. Now I'm trying to use Name, which is wrong?

Comment: @gloopit: exactly. Not wrong per se. Just your selectors were inadequate for the task. :)

Comment: Thanks! i have made an amendment below and answered my own question as still a little confusing

Answer (score 2):

[`Document.querySelector()` uses CSS style selectors.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) For this reason, this line of code is looking for a DOM element of type `all`, not for one with this name:

```
document.querySelector("all")
```

Instead, you can [select elements by name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName) and take the first one found:

```
document.getElementsByName("all")[0]
```

Another alternative would be to assign an id to your element and [select it via `Document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById).

Comment: Thanks! i have made an amendment below and answered my own question as still a little confusing

Answer (score 0):

I have got it semi-working.

I added ID's to my HTML:

```
<fieldset class="activities">
        <legend>Register for Activities</legend>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="all" id="all"> Main Conference — $200</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="js-frameworks" id="framework"> JavaScript Frameworks Workshop — Tuesday 9am-12pm, $100</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="js-libs" id="libs"> JavaScript Libraries Workshop — Tuesday 1pm-4pm, $100</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="express" id="express"> Express Workshop — Tuesday 9am-12pm, $100</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="node" id="node"> Node.js Workshop — Tuesday 1pm-4pm, $100</label>          
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="build-tools" id="build"> Build tools Workshop — Wednesday 9am-12pm, $100</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="npm" id="npm"> npm Workshop — Wednesday 1pm-4pm, $100</label>
      </fieldset>
```

And changed what I was selecting.

```
// Register for Activities section of the form.
document.querySelector(".activities").addEventListener("change", function(){
    var main = document.getElementById("all");
    var framework = document.getElementById("framework");
    var libs = document.getElementById("libs");
    var express = document.getElementById("express");
    var node = document.getElementById("node");
    var build = document.getElementById("build");
    var npm = document.getElementById("npm");

    // If the user selects a workshop, don't allow selection of a workshop at the same date and time -- you should disable the checkbox and visually indicate that the workshop in the competing time slot isn't available.
    if(framework.checked == true) {
        express.disabled = true;
    } else if(express.checked == true) {
        framework.disabled=  true;
    } else if(libs.checked == true) {
        node.disabled = true;
    } else if(node.checked == true) {
        libs.disabled = true;
    } 

    // When a user unchecks an activity, make sure that competing activities (if there are any) are no longer disabled.
    if(framework.checked == false) {
        express.disabled = false;
    } else if(express.checked == false) {
        framework.disabled = false;
    } else if(libs.checked == false) {
        node.disabled = false;
    } else if(node.checked == false) {
        libs.disabled = false;
    } 

    // Calculate running total of price of events selected
});
```

This successfully disables the correct checkboxes when needed. But I am not able to ENable them when I uncheck the clashing boxes.

What is happening? I have tried playing around with my if conditions but no luck so far.

Comment: any ideas @TimoSta?

Answer (score 0):

```
This is how is solve this issue:

//deactivate checkboxes if there is a conflict with scheduling 
$(function() {
    $('[name="js-frameworks"]').change(function() {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $('[name="express"]').prop('disabled', true);
        } else if (!$(this).is(':checked')) {
            $('[name="express"]').prop('disabled', false);
        }
    })
});

$(function() {
    $('[name="express"]').change(function() {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $('[name="js-frameworks"]').prop('disabled', true);
        } else if (!$(this).is(':checked')) {
            $('[name="js-frameworks"]').prop('disabled', false);
        }
    })
});

....
```

Comment: It'd be better if you can dedicate a few words to explain how this code works. Thank you.